# Replacing decimals

Tags: powershell, rename

I have many files that all have a similar formatting. Some are different lengths, but generally they all follow this formatting:

```
First_M_Last_ID_10008.0_DOB_10-19-15_DOS_10-10-10_10.50.24_AM_Ending.
```

I want to replace the `.0`s in the ID with no character and replace the `.`s with `_` without changing the extension. For example if the file is the above with extension .docx I want to keep that so the file doesn't get converted to a text file. I've tried using this code:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName{$_.name -replace ".0",""}
```

But it seems to replace all `0`s in the file with white space. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` has a special meaning in regular expressions. It matches any character except a newline. To match a literal dot you need to escape it with a backslash (`\.`). The other dots you want to replace seem to be preceded by numbers, so you could group the number (`(\d)\.`) and replace the match with the group and an underscore (`${1}_`).

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\.0','' -replace '(\d)\.','${1}_'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the dot.

```
$a = "First_M_Last_ID_10008.0_DOB_10-19-15_DOS_10-10-10_10.50.24_AM_Ending.csv"

$a = $a -replace ("\.0","")

$a
```

Result

```
First_M_Last_ID_10008_DOB_10-19-15_DOS_10-10-10_10.50.24_AM_Ending.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! It worked out.